FluentBit: forward metrics from OpenTelemetry Input to Prometheus Output?
I'm not too sure about whether this is possible, I found the documentation not fully clear in this regards.
Is it possible to have an input of type OpenTelemetry, which receives OTel metrics, and publish them via the Prometheus output, so it can be scraped by the central prom instance?
In the documentation there is the line:

Important Note: The prometheus exporter only works with metric plugins, such as Node Exporter Metrics

But I don't know if metrics part of the OTel input is considered a "metric plugin". Or is that exporter limited to only a few little specific inputs (I couldn't get it working locally with an input of type cpu as well ‍♂️)

Did you consider directly exposing the metrics from the application or OTEL collector? Or is it mandatory that they have to go through fluent-bit?

@SrikanthChekuri I did consider it, and it is possible. But having one central tunnel for all OTel information (logs, traces, metrics) which I can configure freely without having to ever touch the main applications would be preferable IMHO.
